# Rom flashed but phone is stuck showing boot logo

Tags: boot

I flashed my Xolo q2000 with CWM Recovery and an Xperia Z2 rom downloaded from Needrom.  All was well but some features were not working so I once again deleted the cache, and wiped data and so on.  Now when it boots it only shows the Xolo logo on screen, nothing else happens.

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Can you get into Recovery Mode again?  If so, try flashing again.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what happened when unexpected behaviour started?

Answer (score 0):

Go into recovery (generally power + vol down or power + home + vol. down) and flash another stable ROM.
How do I know this? I have bricked many phones a thousand times ;-p